# Atributo contenteditable não funciona

Tags: html, atributos

```
<input type="email" name="email-empresa" id="email-empresa" placeholder="ex: seuemail@domínio.com" class="txt-input" contenteditable="false" value="seuemail@teste.com">
```

Estou com problemas para fazer com que o conteúdo do input não seja editável, pois, mais pra frente, o valor do input será colocado via php, e o usuário não poderá editar seu e-mail a não ser que o mesmo seja um adm do site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contenteditable="false"` pelos vistos não funciona em input, faça assim (`readonly`)

```html
<input type="email" name="email-empresa" id="email-empresa" placeholder="ex: seuemail@domínio.com" class="txt-input" readonly value="seuemail@teste.com">
```

Assim ainda pode posicionar o cursor lá, mas caso não queira pode sempre colocar `disable`:

```html
<input type="email" name="email-empresa" id="email-empresa" placeholder="ex: seuemail@domínio.com" class="txt-input" disabled value="seuemail@teste.com">
```

Comment: perfeito, funcionou de primeira

Comment: Ainda bem @MuriloGambôa.

Answer (score 2):

Basta acrescentar o atributo `readonly`.

```html
<input type="email" name="email-empresa" id="email-empresa" placeholder="ex: seuemail@domínio.com" class="txt-input"  value="seuemail@teste.com" readonly>
```

Leia mais sobre o atributo `readonly` em: [**HTML  readonly Attribute**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)